# How do I add an HTML favicon (mine isn't working)?

Tags: html, favicon

Head:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/> <!-- Here -->
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5aaf8b7460.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.css">
   
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
```

My favicon is in the same directory as `index.html`

However it just shows the favicon as a white page - not working.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does your stylesheet load?

Comment: It does. @JohnSims

Comment: and does the favicon.png file exists and it has valid png format and it has permissions to be read and it is locate at same folder than this html file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

See the full url instead only image name :

Source and more info about :

This is not mandatory, but  it may affect on older browser, check this https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon